# navigating to ViewControllers that aren't on the UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I started using `UITabBarController` and it is great.

The thing is I have a few views that aren't accessed from the UITabBar
(either presented modal programatically or we want to have a button on the top to jump to them)

The thing is that I want to retain the Tab bar visible in these views.
From my understanding mixing `presentViewController` and `UITabBarController` is problematic.

How can I do that? Can I have "hidden" tab bar elements I can reference programatically?

Just to clarify with an example:

Views A,B,C,D are in the tab bar - via the storyboard - everything is peachy.
I NEED to have views E and F clickable from the top navigation (please don't suggest a sliding TabBar or a multiple line UITabBar).
I could just jump to E and F but I want the `UITabBar` to still be visible so the user can jump from E to A for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the good old `UINavigationController` for every tab and just use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:A animated:YES];`

That's how the setup looks in code:

```
SGTabBarViewController *rootVC = [[SGTabBarViewController alloc] init];

SGFirstTabViewController *firstVC = [[SGFirstTabViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC];
SGSecondTabViewController *secondVC = [[SGSecondTabViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondVC];
SGThirdTabViewController *thirdVC = [[SGThirdTabViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:thirdVC];
SGForuthTabViewController *fourhtVC = [[SGForuthTabViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fourhtVC];

rootVC.viewControllers = @[navController1, navController2, navController3, navController4];

self.window.rootViewController = rootVC;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

If you want your `UITabBar` visible on every VC you push just use `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;` on it.

However, there is no way to have `UITabBar` visible on views presented modally.

Comment: and than I bypass the storyboard and every view is on it's own?

Comment: @Boaz - not really, in a storyboard you have to select your vc, then select - Editor - Embed In - Navigation Controller and then you can use push segues in the IB to move between views.

Comment: @Boaz you shouldn't because you are using a storyboard. The code is just an alternative way of what you should do. You should just use the instructions in my previous comment - that's it.